# XSL-FO conditional-page-master-reference keeps rendering 2+ pages using last page master

Tags: layout, xsl-fo

I have this `layout-master-set` definition:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-pages" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="20mm 20mm 0mm 20mm" >
    <fo:region-body margin-top="25mm" margin-bottom="35mm" />
    <fo:region-before extent="20mm" />
    <fo:region-after  extent="30mm"  />
  </fo:simple-page-master>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="last-page" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin="20mm 20mm 0mm 20mm" >
    <fo:region-body margin-top="25mm" margin-bottom="115mm" />
    <fo:region-before extent="20mm" />
    <fo:region-after  extent="110mm" region-name="region-last-page" />
  </fo:simple-page-master>

  <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="pages">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="last" master-reference="last-page"/>
      <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="all-pages"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
  </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

As you can see, I want the last page to render a much bigger `region-after`, but instead I get the large `region-after` on all pages after the first, and the `all-pages` master is only used for the first page?

Does anyone see a problem with that configuration?

PS: using Fop 0.20.5

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks okay. But you should give all regions a name to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The `fo:page-sequence-master` is correctly defined, the problem is the FOP version you are using: 0.20.5 dates back to **2003** (!) and had several bugs and missing features.

At the moment the [latest released version is 1.1](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/download.html#binary), which creates the pages as expected.

*Disclosure: I am a FOP developer (although I haven't been very active for years).*